Perceptually linear gradient using vertex attributes and sRGB surface in Vulkan?
I'm trying to implement a simple color picker using 2 overlapped quads: 1 quad has a horizontal white-to-value gradient, the other quad has a black-to-transparent vertical gradient.

The colors are provided as vertex attributes specified in linear space.
The surface format is VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB
The surface colorspace is VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR
No additional linear-to-srgb or srgb-to-linear conversion is performed in the vertex/pixel shader

The final result is this, which is not what I expect:

The colors are too bright (there is too little black and red).
This is what a correct color picker for red should look like:

Also the (rightmost) slider is wrong too (it interpolates from full white to full black, and the gradient is linear (perceptually non-linear).
So if vertex attribute color is specified as linear (it shouldn't matter because the single channels are either 0 or 1: white is [1,1,1] and red is [1,0,0]) and fragment interpolation is thus done in linear space, why is the final output linear (perceptually non linear) if the surface is sRGB? Shouldn't Vulkan convert between linear to sRGB after the fragment shader?
If I apply a linear-to-srgb conversion in the pixel shader the gradient becomes correct, but the other colors become too dark.

Note that the rightmost slider (black-to-white) is now perceptually linear, but the alpha on the main leftmost picker (black-to-transparent) is still wrong.
If I try to render a texture with a black-to-red gradient and compare it with a gradient generated using vertex attribute colors there is a difference (top is vertex attribs, bottom is texture):

Steps to reproduce:

git clone --recursive https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan
On windows run cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
Change base/VulkanSwapChain.cpp:188 between VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM and VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB
Change vertex data in examples/triangle/triangle.cpp:226 to a red-to-white gradient:

// Setup vertices
std::vector<Vertex> vertexBuffer{
    { {  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } }, // br
    { { -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // bl
    { { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }, // tl
    { {  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } }, // tr
};

or a colored quad:
// Setup vertices
std::vector<Vertex> vertexBuffer{
    { {  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } }, // br
    { { -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f } }, // bl
    { { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // tl
    { {  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }, // tr
};


Change indexes in examples/triangle/triangle.cpp:233 to:

// Setup indices
std::vector<uint32_t> indexBuffer{ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

In my case the results are: 
The top left red gradient looks correct, but the top right one is too dark.
The bottom left red gradient looks too bright, but the bottom right one looks correct.

For color, shader outputs are notionally linear light intensity values. Linear light is not perceptually linear. When you have a primitive rendering a 0 to 1 lerp interpolated gradient, the mid-point linear light value of 0.5 isn't the perceptual midpoint. Perceptually, a linear light value of 0.5 is actually around 0.73, which is why your gradient looks biased towards brighter values.
Using format=VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM is a pass-through with no implicit gamma conversion. For this to make sense for a sRGB display colorspace, your shader must be outputting perceptually linear values (i.e. with gamma correction applied in the shader). This format works for what you are doing because you do actually want 0.5 to be the perceptual midpoint, not a 0.5 linear light intensity midpoint.
If you want to use format=VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRBB then your shader outputs need to output true linear light values, being aware that they are going to be gamma converted later.
One of the main issues developers encounter here is that a lot of input art assets (e.g. textures for UI) claim to be sRGB but they are not really. Getting this "right" needs the whole content pipeline to be configured correctly.
For the 2D color selector, I suspect you'll need something more complex (e.g. HSL interpolation) if you want to look like selectors in other applications. Simple interpolation of RGB values from the triangle corners is going to give you a visible line down the diagonal, and perception of different hues is also not linear.
